# Are there any javascript libs for creating a nice structured (tree) diff for HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, diff

I'm trying to come up with a solution to power a "history view" mechanism that we are using throughout a site. For the UI of this history view I'd like to show the user what changes occurred between two revisions of an object. In other words, a diff.

This is a real challenge because the objects in question are all fairly complex. I figured the best approach was to render each object as HTML and then use some kind of diff tool on the generated HTML to present the differences to the user.

The closest I've come so far to a working solution is with the google-match-patch libraries (http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/). I implemented one of the suggested methods described in the wiki for using google-match-patch with structured content (http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/Plaintext) but the results aren't quite right. For reference, here is my (somewhat crude - I was just testing the concept) code: https://gist.github.com/921264

**My question:** As is explained on the above wiki page, "The correct solution is to use a tree-based diff, match and patch." Can anyone suggest such a library written in JavaScript?

I tried DaisyDiff (java) and was unimpressed with the results.

---

**EDIT**: [Here is a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dustmason/XyzK4/) for show-and-tell!

---

**EDIT #2: SHARING IS CARING**: https://github.com/GenuineParts/TableDiff

Comment: All of this for a simple history view? How is that data stored? Does the page in question refresh itself or does the user return to it? I can think of a couple of simpler solutions for this scenario.

Comment: Please share ideas for simpler solutions! The data: each history "snapshot" is a JSON string that we parse into a native object. I don't follow your question regarding the page itself

Comment: The page that shows the history. Give sample data please. What type of history are we referring to?

Comment: I posted a nice working sample in the jsfiddle

Comment: @DustMason did you press save? >.> Try adding it to the OP, the fiddle is a bit of a mess.

Comment: I certainly did press save. I should have said NOT QUITE working sample... What you see in the fiddle is as close as I've been able to get with the diff-match-patch libs

Comment: @DustMason that's your data ?

Comment: Yes that is a simple example. Here is a demo of our current history feature http://vimeo.com/16806849 . It works very well, but was written in a way that is hard to maintain. I want to abstract the "snapshot" comparison into something more reusable, hence the HTML diff idea.

Comment: I REALLY appreciate you sharing that, was struggling on comparing HTML strings, and this solved my problem.  I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that it has a finite amount of HTML tags in a document it can support, because there are only so many unicode characters.  I used the same approach that you posted, which was very helpful, but instead of using unicode characters, I am using numbered place holders, for example:

{{0}}, {{1}}, {{2}} instead of unicode characters.  This gives a much larger amount of HTML that it can support.

Comment: this is a good improvement on the solution! perhaps even replacing "{{" and "}}" with two different high-range unicode characters could (almost) totally get rid of the chance of collisions with real content