# Some way to retrieve ckeditor text changes when "change" is fired

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm setting up a ckeditor instance and listen to the `editor.on("change")` event to get notified of changes.

Is there a way, whenever something changes in the document, either a added character or changed markup, to receive an event and from there find out the part that has changed?

Inspecting the data sent with the "change" event didn't give me the desired results, it doesn't seem to contain the added changes.

I know there's the "key" event, that sends me the keycode typed, is there something else for changed markup (like when clicking on the "bold" button?

Or is there another way intirely?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no such way. At least not in CKEditor. It's a matter of diffing tree stuctures and the problem was on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673228/are-there-any-javascript-libs-for-creating-a-nice-structured-tree-diff-for-htm

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729510/does-ckeditor-provide-a-property-for-when-the-change-event-was-triggered-by-mo

Comment: Thanks for your help! For my use case I'm reacting on the change event and diff (using jsDiff) the current text I get with getSnapshot with a previous version to create a kind of patch list. That seems to work well.

Comment: @oleq diffing two large tree structures every time a keystroke is hit seems rather heavy handed!

Answer (score 1):

The "change" event fired by CKEditor is quite dumb and won't give you what you want.

You'll have to ignore it and get your hands dirty using [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the DOM that will give you so much info that your first problem will be how to handle all of that, how to ignore internal CKEditor changes, etc...